# How do I use the "Remove display from desktop" feature on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-display, display-settings

It says that: "This display will be available exclusively for special-purpose apps that require it."

[image]

So my question is, what are these special purpose apps?

For example, I set this option on my drawing tablet display, and it turned it off. But then I don't know how to make it so my drawing app is the only one exclusively using that display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What are these special purpose apps?

[Turn On or Off Remove Display from Desktop in Windows 11 Tutorial | Windows 11 Forum](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-remove-display-from-desktop-in-windows-11.7632/) lists a few:

> The Specialized Display feature enables a display to be dedicated to a
> specific purpose, such as:
>
> - Fixed-function arcade/gaming rigs like cockpit/driving/flight/military simulators
> - Medical imaging devices that have custom panels (e.g. grayscale X-ray displays)
> - Dedicated video monitoring scenarios
> - Monitor panel testing and validation (e.g. in the factory)
> - Video walls

#### I don't know how to make it so my drawing app is the only one exclusively using that display?

Your drawing app would have to make use of **the exclusive-access API to take control of it.**

See [What's the use for the "Remove Display from Desktop feature"? : r/windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/18qgr2k/whats_the_use_for_the_remove_display_from_desktop/):

> When a display is a part of the desktop system, the OS can extend the
> desktop to it and show app windows on it. However, apps can take
> exclusive control of a display via its device handle and draw on it.
> In the past, most video games did this.
>
> When you remove a display from the desktop, it displays nothing until
> an app invokes the exclusive-access API to take control of it.

Comment: I saw that too but those are just broad terms imo. I'm more looking for a name of an application (e.g. Microsoft Word, etc) or better yet, how do I make it use any application

Comment: I already extended the answer